# How to run sub-query first and only once

Tags: mysql

How do I get MySQL to run the sub-query first and only once? Right now MySQL runs the inner query for every row in table t1, which is a performance disaster.

```
explain select * from t1 where uid in (select id from t0);
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t1    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 18954249 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t0    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    12749 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

If you perform an `inner join`, you'll get your desired outcome.

From:

```
select * from t1 where uid in (select id from t0);
```

To:

```
select * from t1 join t0 on t1.t0id = t0.id
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join

Answer (score 4):

The below 2 would work faster than your current `query`, which one scales better depends on your Database Structure

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  t1 t
  JOIN t0 ON ( t.uid = t0.id )      << If there are 2 row matches on table `t0`, it shall return duplicated rows (t1 table contents duplicated, you could use a distinct to avoid such cases) OR use the second query instead
```

**AND**

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  t1 t
  WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from t0 WHERE t0.id = t.uid)
```

Comment: Is MySQL *still* unable to properly optimize sub-queries? That's disappointing.

Comment: Yes, here's more info on optimizing such queries http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html